# Convert multiple square bracket values into array php

Tags: php, regex, arrays

I've got the following data in a db

```
[508] [blah-blah-blah] Random Text
[510] [hello-hello-hello] More random text
[542] [stuff-stuff-stuff] Even more text
```

This is in quite a lot of db cells. The whole block of text is in a cell and each row of the text is separated by a carriage return.

Ideally i want the number in the first square bracket on each line into array values. The data i want to end up with is:

```
array(508,510,542)
```

More importantly, i want to see how to efficiently get that first data structure into a array. i feel like there should be a simple efficient way to use it, but, aside from some really complex regex i cannot see how to do it :(

Any help would be magical!

Comment: Which db are you using?

Comment: Mysql is the database :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PHP you can match the numbers using [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for the literal brackets using `preg_match_all()`

```
<?php

    $string = '[508] [blah-blah-blah] Random Text
    [510] [hello-hello-hello] More random text
    [542] [stuff-stuff-stuff] Even more text';
    preg_match_all ('!(?<=\[)([0-9]+)(?=\])!',$string,$matches);
    print_r($matches[0]);

?>
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 508
    [1] => 510
    [2] => 542
)
```

To handle all of the records from the database, you would do something like this:

```
    $result = mysqli_query($sql);
$records = array(); 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){


        preg_match_all ('!(?<=\[)([0-9]+)(?=\])!',$row['my_text_field'],$matches);
        foreach($matches[0] as $value){     
        $records[]=$value;
        }

}

print_r($records);
```

Comment: This would fail if there are more than one column that starts with a number on any given line.

Answer (score 1):

Given that your numbers always appear at the start of each line, the expression is pretty simple:

```
$input = <<<EOM
[508] [blah-blah-blah] Random Text
[510] [hello-hello-hello] More random text
[542] [stuff-stuff-stuff] Even more text
EOM;

preg_match_all('/^\[(\d+)\]/m', $input, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

I'm using the `/m` modifier to enable multiline mode, causing `^` to match the start of each line.

Answer (score 0):

From the DB directly:

```
mysqli_query("SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING(your_column_name, 1), ']', 1) FROM tablename");
```

[SUBSTRING(str, pos)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) works like substr() would in php in that it extract a slice of the original string.

`SUBSTRING(your_column_name, 1)` means copy "your_column_name" starting from index 1 to the end.

```
[508] [blah-blah-blah] Random Text
Becomes
508] [blah-blah-blah] Random Text
```

[SUBSTRING_INDEX(str, C, X)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) copy the entire string str until the Xth occurence of character C

`SUBSTRING_INDEX(str, ']', 1)` means copy the the entire string until the first occurence of ]

```
508] [blah-blah-blah] Random Text
```

Becomes

```
508
```

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ: Indeed, I misunderstood and thought one line in the exemple was one row in the database. That is one weird data set ...

Comment: It's cool. I'm not one for `-1`ing a potential answer. Definitely is a messed up entry, but stuff like this happens out there all the time. My favorite phrase is "We have a file in Word"...

Comment: Even if you could find a way to find all matches, you would still have to turn this into multiple rows to be effective.